# give role when a user add reaction Discord.net

Tags: vb.net, discord.net

I'm trying to add feedback (thump up + thump down) to be embedded in EmbedBuilder message. If a user thumbs-up then apply the the role "good" to him, if he thumbs-down apply the role "bad", also if removed his reaction type (thump..up/dawn) will remove his role (win/lose).

message_txt_Embed is the embedded message that will be sent.

```
Private Async Function onMsg(message As SocketMessage) As Task
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If message.Source = MessageSource.Bot Then
        'ignore bot repeat message message
Else

   If message.Content = message_txt_Embed.text Then

            Dim msg As String = message.Content
            Dim embed As New EmbedBuilder With {
      .Title = msg,
      .Description = "No Description",
      .Color = New Discord.Color(255, 0, 0)
       }
            Await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", False, embed)


            '''''' what i try to add reaction for user's who add reaction

            Dim guild As SocketGuild = (CType(message.Channel, SocketGuildChannel)).Guild
            Dim emote As IEmote = guild.Emotes.First(Function(e) e.Name = ":thumbsup:")
            Await guild.Users.AddReactionAsync(emote)

            ''''''
        End If

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
End If
```

How does it work when I change message_txt_Embed.text for example to "test", and then run bot. If I typed "test" [as message_txt_Embed.text], then create embed msg.

My point is: How can I apply a role for the user when reaction is added(thump..up/dawn) and also remove role if he deleted his reaction.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by: "How does it work when I change message_txt_Embed.text for example to "test", and then run bot. If I typed "test" [as message_txt_Embed.text], then create embed msg."

Comment: @Anu6is
okey let it be when bot run will send embedded message for specific channel.id "45.....", and if user add reaction (thump up) will add role to him as "win"  /And if he removed (thump up) reaction then remove role from him if found "win"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd like to clear up some issues with you sample code. See the comments below

```vb
'This function is only called when a message is recieved by the client.
'It is not going to be called when a user adds a reaction to a message.
'As such, no logic should be included in here in relation to reactions.
Private Async Function onMsg(message As SocketMessage) As Task

If message.Source = MessageSource.Bot Then
        'Instead of having an empty bode in your condition, you could use:

        'If Not message.Source = MessageSource.Bot Then 
        '   execute your logic
        'End If     

        'The code above would remove the need for includeing an ELSE section 
        'and no longer require the IF section to be empty
Else
    If message.Content = message_txt_Embed.text Then
        Dim msg As String = message.Content
        Dim embed As New EmbedBuilder With {
            .Title = msg,
            .Description = "No Description",
            .Color = New Discord.Color(255, 0, 0)
       }

       Await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", False, embed)

       Dim guild As SocketGuild = (CType(message.Channel, SocketGuildChannel)).Guild

       'If you are trying to get the standard thumbsup emoji this is not going to work
       'SocketGuild#Emotes is a collection of custom emotes that are available in the guild.
       'If this thumbsup is in fact a custom emote you'd access the name withoug the ':'
       Dim emote As IEmote = guild.Emotes.First(Function(e) e.Name = ":thumbsup:")
       Await guild.Users.AddReactionAsync(emote) 'This is not a valid function.
    End If
End If
```

**Solution:**
- Create a List(Of Ulong) that would be used to store the ID of any message that should give a role when a reaction is added. This ensures that roles are not given for reacting to any and every message in the channel.
- Use the ReactionAdded and ReactionRemoved events to listen for reactions being added or removed by users.

You can find documentation on the [ReactionAdded Event here](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.BaseSocketClient.html#Discord_WebSocket_BaseSocketClient_ReactionAdded)

```vb
'Any time a message is created with the purpose of adding reaction roles
'that message id should be added to this list. 
'This example does not include code for populating this list!
Private ReadOnly ReactionMessages As New List(Of ULong)
```

```vb
'Subscribe to the ReactionAdded and ReactionRemoved events (code not included)
```

**Reaction Added** - Add Role

```vb
    Private Async Function ReactionAdded(cache As Cacheable(Of IUserMessage, ULong), channel As ISocketMessageChannel, reaction As SocketReaction) As Task
        If Not reaction.User.IsSpecified Then Return

        'cache.id is the id of the message the user added the reaction to
        'Check if the message the user is reacting to is a valid reaction message
        'If valid, the message id should exist in our ReactionMessages collection
        'Valid reaction messages are the only message that should assign or remove roles
        If ReactionMessages.Contains(cache.Id) Then
            Dim role As IRole = Nothing

            'The unicode string ( and ) is used when comparing Discord emojis
            If reaction.Emote.Name.Equals("") Then
                'Retrieve the "good role" from the guild, using the role id
                role = DirectCast(channel, SocketGuildChannel).Guild.GetRole(123456789)
            ElseIf reaction.Emote.Name.Equals("") Then
                'Retrieve the "bad role" from the guild, using the role id
                role = DirectCast(channel, SocketGuildChannel).Guild.GetRole(987654321)
            End If

            'Only if the role was found within the guild should we attempt to add it to the user
            If role IsNot Nothing Then Await DirectCast(reaction.User.Value, SocketGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role)
        End If
    End Function
```

**Reaction Removed** - Remove role

```vb
    Private Async Function ReactionRemoved(cache As Cacheable(Of IUserMessage, ULong), channel As ISocketMessageChannel, reaction As SocketReaction) As Task
        If Not reaction.User.IsSpecified Then Return

        'cache.id is the id of the message the user is reacting to
        'Check if the message the user is reacting to is a valid reaction message
        'If valid, the message id should exist in our ReactionMessages collection
        'Valid reaction messages are the only message that should assign or remove roles
        If ReactionMessages.Contains(cache.Id) Then
            Dim role As IRole = Nothing
            Dim user As SocketGuildUser = reaction.User.Value

            'The unicode string ( and ) is used when comparing Discord emojis
            If reaction.Emote.Name.Equals("") Then
                'Retrieve the "good role" from the guild, using the role id
                role = DirectCast(channel, SocketGuildChannel).Guild.GetRole(123456789)
            ElseIf reaction.Emote.Name.Equals("") Then
                'Retrieve the "bad role" from the guild, using the role id
                role = DirectCast(channel, SocketGuildChannel).Guild.GetRole(987654321)
            End If

            'If the role was found within the guild and the user currently has the role assigned, remove the role from the user
            If role IsNot Nothing AndAlso user.Roles.Any(Function(r) r.Id = role.Id) Then Await user.RemoveRoleAsync(role)
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: @Bego.That's your same old code that I added comments to. At that particular line I added the comment `This is not a valid function`. How about reading the entire solution provided and trying to understand what's said.

Comment: sure, i saw "This is not a valid function", and i tired, but i asked cause after many failed. i will try my hard, rn, hope i get it, to make as answer.

Comment: it worked now, but its only add role, when i remove my reaction , not remove my role. it can only add

Comment: Thanks, i fixed all of them.